# Google map not loading fully

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app where I use a map and a test app. The map is loading fine on the test app, and is zooming in smoothly without any flicker, shows all details at that level of zoom. However, on my actual app, the map does not load fully and when I try to zoom in, it is just like stretching an image - the details are not showing as relevant for that level of zoom. Please let me know what might be wrong. Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you post some of your code? so that other members here can help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like height problem in the map. Check if you have static value, match_parent etc. Without logs cannot say more.

Comment: It is not about the height, I am sure of that. Even if I have match_parent, it shows the top-level map but when I try to zoom in, there is no further loading of the details.

Comment: If this is not height problem.First I will go through logcat(full output) and check if theres is any weird log, exception etc. Secondly I will check if there is lot of GC logs at the same time, more less. If there is something is creating and destroying very often. Also please post screenshot if you could or some code to check what is wrong.